# let $\mathrm{GCD}(a,b)=1$. If $d\mid ac$ and $d\mid bc$, then show $d\mid c$. Do not use the Prime number Factorization Theorem.

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

> Let $\mathrm{GCD}(a,b)=1$. If $d\mid ac$ and $d\mid bc$, then show $d\mid c$. Do not use the Prime number Factorization Theorem.

I having a hard time figuring what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Because $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, there are integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=1$. This result is sometimes called the *Bezout Identity.*

Multiply through by $c$.

Comment: as in replace a and b with the like ac =dk, and bc =d q, so that a= dk/c and b=dq/c or just mutiply the whole thing by c